# Is there a good alternative to OpenSCAD?

Tags: open-source, 3d, cross-platform

Is there a good alternative to OpenSCAD that has simple syntax and easy download option? I want it to be cross-platform. It should be open-source too. (Free for commercial use is a bonus.)

Edit:
The reason I'm looking for a new software is simply that I want more export options like `.glb` and I want a dark themed editor UI.

Comment: This type of question appears to be opinion based, which may cause it to be closed. Consider to edit your question with specifics you seek or that you find objectionable in OpenSCAD. I use OpenSCAD and find it easy to download and find it has simple syntax. This is an opinion and responses to your currently formed question would also be opinions.

Comment: Edited. Please check.